# Sort method c# string to char

Tags: char

I'm trying to do Sort method, however i get this error:
IndexOutOfRangeException, on the line `if(chars[i] > chars1[y])`. Amount is equal to 25

```
        string temp1;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            for (int y = i + 1; y < amount - 1; y++) 
            {
                var chars = Duomenys[i].Pozicija.ToCharArray();
                var chars1 = Duomenys[y].Pozicija.ToCharArray();
                if (chars[i] > chars1[y])
                {............}
```

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException indicates that either i or y is greater than the length of that string.  Set a breakpoint and check that that i isn't greater than the length of chars and y isn't greater than the length of chars1.

Comment: You're setting y = i + 1.  If amount is 25, last index of i is 24.  In your inner loop, you set y = 25; y < 24; y++

Maybe not your issue, but that's one thing I see right off the bat.  I'm not really sure what the non-english stuff is doing, so I'm just looking at your loop structure, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same indices (`i` and `y`) to identify locations within the array `Duomenys` and `chars`/`chars1`, which seem like very different things.  Can't tell what you should be doing instead, given the lack of information provided.